# Вывод обьектов в строку JS

Tags: javascript, строки, объекты

пример обьэкта

```
users = {
Genry:'genry@gmail.com',
Osvald:'osvald@gmail.com',
Henry:'henry@gmail.com'
}
```

( сам обьект формируется с двух массивов )

```
usersArr = ['Genry','Osvald','Henry']
emailsArr = ['genry@gmail.com','osvald@gmail.com','henry@gmail.com']
```

нужно вывести в следующий результат

```
Genry genry@gmail.com
Osvald osvald@gmail.com
Henry henry@gmail.com
```

( возможно нужно изменить подход, и не формировать обьект из масивов для последующего вывода, но нужно чтобы все было организовано в одной форме с данными, к примеру в обьекте )

это в целом будет писать бот, так что в реальной задаче используется node.js, но вопрос - как такой вывод сделать на чистом JS, если есть уточнения касательно Node.js буду так же благодарен, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)** - взять все ключи объекта

**[Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)** - взять все значения объекта

Пользуйтесь, не стесняйтесь

Цикл по **[Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)**  вполне тоже уместен

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```